# Add variable to require in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add variable `bgImg` to `background-image` URL?

```
let bgImg = props=>props.bgImg;

//this will show error
export const Users = styled.div`
    background-image: url(${require('../../assets/images/' + {bgImg} + '.svg')});
    background-image: url(${require('../../assets/images/' + ${bgImg} + '.svg')});
`;
```

I have tried this and it didn't work

```
let x = '../../assets/images/';
let bgImg = props=>props.bgImg;
let result = x + bgImg + ".svg";
```

Result with error

```
../../assets/images/function bgImg(props) {
    return props.bgImg;
}.svg
```

How can I get that return property?

Comment: You're defining `bgImg` as a function. What is it you expect to pass into that function? Nothing in what you've shown actually calls it.

Comment: `props` is already in scope, why not just do `let bgImg = props.bgImg`?

Comment: Create the string before you pass them to `require`, it should be easier one.

Comment: You can avoid all the problem by using the svg inline as a react element and rendering the <svg>...</svg> directly into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The feature are you looking for maybe *dynamic import*

```js
import("./math").then(math => {
  console.log(math.add(16, 26));
});
```

But specifically what you'll find very useful is *Loadable* implementation:

```js
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const LoadableOtherComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./OtherComponent'),
  loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>,
});

const MyComponent = () => (
  <LoadableOtherComponent/>
);
```

And maybe that's what you're looking for:

```js
Loadable.Map({
  loader: {
    Bar: () => import('./Bar'),
    i18n: () => fetch('./i18n/bar.json').then(res => res.json()),
  },
  render(loaded, props) {
    let Bar = loaded.Bar.default;
    let i18n = loaded.i18n;
    return <Bar {...props} i18n={i18n}/>;
  },
});
```